# None items in subdirectories with Visible="false" in NuGet package shows subdirectory folders

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I want to add data files (txt files for example) to a custom NuGet package that are in subdirectories within the package, and save them into the output directory.

First I had these data files in the contentFiles saved to the output directory, but they were being shown in the solution explorer in Visual Studio, and we didn't want that.

I then put the data files into the build folder in the subdirectory folders, and was using a targets file to save them to the output directory and setting Visible="false", this worked well except for that the subdirectories are being included in the solution explorer, not the actual files, just the subdirectories.  I then tried putting them into a native folder within the build folder, but ended up with the same thing.

this is my nuspec file

```
<metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title></title>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="build\native\sub1\data.txt" target="build\native\sub2\data.txt" />
    <file src="build\native\sub2\data.txt" target="build\native\sub2\data.txt" />
<-- bunch of other files -->
  </files>
```

this is my targets file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)*.dll" Visible="false">            
            <Link>%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)native/**" Visible="false">
            <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I want this to hide everything about the NuGet package and save them in the output directory, but the 'data1' and 'data2' folders show up in my solution explorer, but empty, so I know the targets file is hitting them.

According to this, if I'm reading this right, it might be a bug, https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1126 but I'm not sure.

I also may be going about this the completely wrong way, and if so I'm open to any possibilities.

Comment: Did you try using an XML element instead of an attribute? `<Visible>false</Visible>`

Comment: @MattWard yes I have, I get the same result.

Comment: the issue you listed is unrelated, it was caused by duplicate items due to incorrect usage as Rainer pointed out, which is not happening in your case. In your case, the project system knows about a folder, but doesn't hide it even though all items in the folder are not visible. MSBuild doesn't have the concept of a folder or directory, only files, so it's impossible to give the project system metadata about a folder. You'd need to report this to the project system team to see if they think it's a bug or not.